# How to achieve an RxJS operator like concatMap() with a queue size of 1?

Tags: rxjs

`concatMap()` will exhaust input observables in order. It will move on to the next input observable if the current one completes. Input observables will be queued and processed one by one. This is almost what I want.

I want a slightly different behavior: I want an operator that does the same as `concatMap()`, but with a queue length of 1. That is, an operator that will exhaust the current observable, but while doing that, keep only the most recent new input observable, instead of queueing them all. How can I achieve this?

Edit: `switchMap()` is not a solution, because I don't want to cancel the current observable when the next one arrives. I want to exhaust it and then move on to the most recent next one.

Edit 2: `exhaustMap()` is not a solution, because it will ignore subsequent observables as long as one is still being consumed.

Comment: Sounds like [`switchMap()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/switchMap)

Comment: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/exhaustMap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Create a custom operator based on `mergeMap`. Cache the latest value and once active observable completes throws the latest observable into the stream and repeat.

Full example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rx-playground-wufgck?file=index.ts).

```js
function concatLatest<T, O extends Observable<unknown>>(
  project: (value: T, index: number) => O
): OperatorFunction<T, ObservedValueOf<O>> {
  let subj: BehaviorSubject<O> | null = null;
  let latestObservable: O = null;

  return mergeMap((val, i) => {
    latestObservable = defer(() =>
      project(val, i).pipe(
        tap({
          complete: () => {
            if (latestObservable) {
              subj.next(latestObservable);
              latestObservable = null;
            } else {
              subj.complete();
              subj = null;
            }
          },
        })
      )
    ) as O;

    if (subj) {
      return EMPTY;
    }

    subj = new BehaviorSubject(latestObservable);

    return subj.pipe(mergeAll());
  });
}
```

Comment: I like it, thanks. I will try to make it more functional by getting rid of the mutable variables but I haven't figured out how yet. A question though, why did you use `tap()` instead of `finalize()`?

Comment: that's up to you which one to use, finalize will be called upon completion/error, `tap` with complete callback will be called only upon completion. If the error occurs `complete` won't be called. So this is something you need to think of for your use case. My answer covers happy path only, cover error case based on your needs.
If you manage to get rid of the mutable variable, let me know. I'm curious what it will look like. You need to have some variable inside the closure to track latest emission.